# No return in `storeFile` method after uploading large files to FTP

Tags: java, ftp

I was uploading large file to FTP, and it was successfully uploaded but no return in `storeFile` method

**core code:**

```
ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftp.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
ftp.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
if(!ftp.storeFile(filename, input))
{
    return result;
}
```

**The stack information:**

```
"Thread-8731" #8873 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fed5034c000 nid=0x6489 runnable [0x00007fecb24f1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x000000054d04d858> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:182)
    - locked <0x000000054d04d858> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58)
    - locked <0x000000054d04d858> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:314)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.getReply(FTP.java:692)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.completePendingCommand(FTPClient.java:1813)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:672)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:624)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:1976)
```

Comment: Can you clarify more, your title is **failed to upload ...** but in your description, you mentioned that file is uploaded, please be consistent.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't describe it clearly. I have changed it ~

Comment: Still unclear what you're asking. Every non-`void` method must throw an exception or return a value. Which is it?

Comment: no exception, no return ,that's the problem

Comment: So do you mean that the method never finishes? How long do you wait? Show us FTP server log file.

Comment: Found a few days ago upload the file thread did not stop, and then found the problem stack information as above